# Google Sheets sparkline bar graph horizontal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a sparkline bar graph where the bars appear horizontally, like so:

[image]

But I can only find the option to display the graph bars vertically.

Any suggestions on how I would be able to achieve this, where negative values appear to the left of the positive values?

Comment: FYI, in case you're still actively using this, Sheets had a recent major update that allows for a much cleaner and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sadly, there is no vertical version of the "winloss" Sparkline.

However, you can simulate this with a bunch of "bar" Sparklines.

### New Solution (Lambda Update)

Sheet's new `Lambda` method supports SparkLines. You can just put a single formula into B1 now:

```
=MAP(
  FILTER(A:A,A:A),
  LAMBDA(min,max,LAMBDA(a,SPARKLINE(
  {
    IF(a>0,ABS(min),a-min),
    ABS(a)
  },{
    "charttype","bar";
    "max",max-min;
    "color1","white";
    "color2",IF(a>0,"green","red")
  })))
  (MIN(A:A),MAX(A:A))
)
```

It essentially works the same way as the old solution, but with better efficiency, since it stores the min/max values in the outer Lambda's parameters.

### Old Solution

```
=SPARKLINE(
{
  IF(A1>0,
    ABS(MIN(A:A)),
    A1-MIN(A:A)),
  ABS(A1)
},
{
  "charttype","bar";
  "max",MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A);
  "color1","white";
  "color2",IF(A1>0,"green","red")
})
```

The downside is that if you increase the number of entries, you have to drag the formula some more. However, it does interpret blank values as 0, so if you know you will never exceed a certain number of entries, you can drag it to that number of rows. (No, `SPARKLINE()` does not work with `ArrayFormula()`.)

### How it works:

Basically, it uses a two-color bar chart where white is the first color to give the appearance of empty space.

- For positive values, it draws a white bar of width `ABS(MIN(A:A))` then the green bar of width `A1`.
- For negative values, it draws a white bar of width `A1-MIN(A:A)`, then draws the red bar of length of width `ABS(A1)`.
- It automatically normalizes and adjusts to the proper width with `MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)`.

Comment: I have been looking all over for something that would do this!  Thank you.  The only thing I changed was adding a ,0 to the MIN()  calculations (MIN(A:A,0) because I wanted 0 to be the start even if I didn't have an amount that low.  I would have never figured this out on my own though.

Comment: @Nigel No problem. I've also edited the formula for readability too. You can add line breaks to formulas to make them less headache inducing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for providing a brief solution.

Just a minor correction to the formula provided in the previous comment: (There should be a semicolon before the ABS formula instead of a comma:

```
=MAP(
  FILTER(A:A,A:A),
  LAMBDA(min,max,LAMBDA(a,SPARKLINE(
  {
    IF(a>0,ABS(min),a-min);
    ABS(a)
  },{
    "charttype","bar";
    "max",max-min;
    "color1","white";
    "color2",IF(a>0,"green","red")
  })))
  (MIN(A:A),MAX(A:A))
)
```